# How to merge edge loops?

Tags: modeling, vertices

How do you merge edge loops? They say <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>M</kbd>  but that merges the edge loops to the middle of it.

What I want to do is is like this, not bridge because bridge will make new faces. I just want merge.
[image]

Comment: select both edge and press space and type Bridge Edge Loops hit enter

Comment: But that will make new faces. I only need to merge them.

Comment: when u press Bridge Edge Loops press f6 and tick mark merge

Comment: Please add the answer as an actual answer and remove the "solved" from the question title.

Answer (score 1):

Merging is the way to go, although differently.

First you want to select two vertices you want to merge to a single vertex of the final model.

[image: The two selected vertecies]

After that hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to merge and select *At center*.

[image: Merged vertecies]

Repeat this process for each vertex. Done.

[image: The final product]